# Xpage Style Not getting Applied on Lotus Notes Client

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, xpinc

Location document of the ID using lotus client uses IE (Internet Explorer) as browser. An Xpage with styles applied for Table cell and Tabs (for tabbed panel) works when Xpage is opened on IE. However when same Xpage is opened on Lotus Notes client, styles are not getting applied for Table and Tab panels.However styles are getting applied for panels (for both client and web). All styles are mentioned on CSS which are included on Xpage resource.

Comment: are you sure this is not a cache thing? restart lotus notes and see if you get the same result

Comment: Yes lotus notes client was restarted to make sure that it was not cache issue. problem still persists.

Comment: Probably adding some code snippet would help.

Answer (score 1):

The Notes client caches styles when rendering xpages, and the cache persists even when the client is restarted.

When you have an xpage open in the Notes client, the keyboard shortcut Ctrl-Shift-Delete should produce a prompt that says "Delete all private data permanently?".
Click OK on that prompt, then close and reopen the xpage, and any style changes should take effect.